# EditorFor doesnt display model value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, editorfor

Im trying to display a Combo and a Text field. The combo show OK and get the value and the list from the model. There are 6 others combos and all working OK. But `SalesPrice` is the only Text field and is empty.

[image]

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PriceSourceSelected, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PriceSourceSelected, Model.PriceSourceList, "Seleccione Origen", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PriceSourceSelected, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SalesPrice, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SalesPrice, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control numericOnly", @type = "number" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SalesPrice, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Checking Local Variables while debuging the View I can see SalesPrice have the correct value:

[image]

**EDIT**

DisplayFor is working OK. So I guess is a decimal separator issue.

[image]

Comment: It's probably because the type of the property is a nullable decimal and you are forcing the input's type attribute to number which does not properly support decimals (probably because of the separator) I have a feeling that's the issue.  Try setting the type attribute to text, or just skip it altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Try using @Html.TextBoxFor(). Sorry for the brief answer/suggestion, I can't add comments yet.

Comment: I just try DisplayFor. and is working ok, check the question

Comment: I think you're right because you're saying it's type number but in that culture there is a comma. Try removing "type=number" and try again with EditorFor or TextBoxFor

Answer (score 0):

I solved changing uiCulture in my Web.Config

```
  <system.web>
    <globalization uiCulture="en" culture="en-US" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Configuration.CBSPassword,**"", "CBSPassword"**, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Password", Type = "password" } })
```

I added the `stringHtmlFieldName` parameter value in my case CBSPassword and it worked.